# Plots that look like coral

Tags: r, distributions, ggplot2

This is a rather unorthodox question. I have data sets with demographic information about coral from 3 different data-collecting dives (height, diameter, whether or not there was bleaching, whether or not there was disease). I would like to compare the demographic data from these dives, and it would be really cool if my plot itself could be both informative, and actually resemble coral. Is this too ambitious?

If it is relevant, I am using R and ggplot

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a mockup? Like something in MS Paint even. This question also belongs on Stackoverflow, since it's a programming question, not a stats question. Also -- consider whether "looking like coral" is a good idea with respect to readability.

Comment: Thanks ssdecontrol. You're right, the question is too ambiguous. Ideally I would like there to be branches like this: https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1536&bih=735&q=coral&oq=coral&gs_l=img.3..0l10.621.946.0.1124.6.5.0.0.0.0.136.136.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.img..5.1.135.0.0GGJyZssl04#imgrc=99CAnaV8pAp3OM:

Comment: Except only 3 branches of course

Comment: I don't know if the code would be too ambitious; that depends in part on your coding sophistication. However, this sounds a lot like [chartjunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk) to me. I would avoid doing this.

Comment: I came here to make gung's point.  Decisions on data communication plots should be about showing the data clearly.  It's not clear that making the plot look like coral is helping this.

Comment: +1 for the novel question, but I would agree that this wouldn't help in understanding the data; it would just complicate it. I would look at plots from this link and choose the one that could be best adopted to the information you have: http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html